# How to compute this recursion in linear time?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, computational-complexity, recursive-algorithms, matrix-equations

Can the following iterative update on a $n$-element vector $\mathbf{x}_t$ be computed in $O(n)$ computations?
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{x}_{t+1}
& = a_t\mathbf{y}_t + \mathbf{A}_t \mathbf{x}_t \,,\\
\mathbf{A}_{t+1}
& = \mathbf{A}_t + b_t \mathbf{y}_t \mathbf{z}_t^T \,.
\end{align*}
Here $a_t$, $b_t$ are (random) scalars, $\mathbf{y}_t$ and $\mathbf{z}_t$ are $n$-element (random) column vectors and $\mathbf{A}_t$ is a $n \times n$ matrix. Without loss of generality, we may assume $\mathbf{A}_0 = \mathbf{0}_{n\times n}$ such that, e.g., $\mathbf{x}_1 = a_0 \mathbf{y}_0$.

When $n$ is large, an explicit computation of $\mathbf{A}_t \mathbf{x}_t$ may be prohibitively expensive.  We could instead compute
$$
\mathbf{A}_t \mathbf{x}_t = \sum_{n=0}^{t-1} b_n \mathbf{y}_n ( \mathbf{z}_n^T \mathbf{x}_t ) \,,
$$
which takes $O(nt)$ computations rather than $O(n^2)$. Unfortunately, as $t$ grows this also may become too slow.

Note that $\mathbf{A}_t$ is only used in the context $\mathbf{A}_t \mathbf{x}_t$. I do not want to store this matrix explicitly, because of its size, so I am looking if a way exists for rewrite the update using only several $n$-element vectors.

I tried storing a vector representing $\mathbf{A}_t \mathbf{x}_t$, but I could not find a $O(n)$ update for this vector.

Comment: If the answer to the question above is inconclusive or negative, I would also like to consider the special case where $\mathbf{z}_t = \mathbf{y}_t$, in which case $\mathbf{A}_t$ is symmetric for all $t$.

Comment: The main thing I do not understand about your question is that you have an update formula for $\mathbf{A}_t$ and $\mathbf{x}_t$ with the subscript $t$ denoting the iteration index, yet all your variables contain the subscript and they do not have any update formula. I would suggest removing the subscripts, or in the least stating something like $\mathbf{y}_{t+1} = \mathbf{y}_t$ (removing subscript for a constant is better).

Comment: Actually, $a_t$, $b_t$, $\mathbf{y}_t$ and $\mathbf{z}_t$ are not constant. These quantities are random and their distribution may depend in some way on the time $t$. For instance, the sequence $\mathbf{y}_t$ may form a Markov chain. I'm sorry that this was unclear.

Comment: Ah ok, I would have caught that better if you said random process rather than just random, but now I see.